# Alpine js table editable rows

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have the table as Alpine component. I need to update data into cell of my table. I use 'input' as a target element to dynamically fill it my server data. But when i try to change data into my "input value", i don't know how to get changed data.

```html
<table x-data="collection" x-init="getCollections()" class="table is-striped is-fullwidth">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:center">Collection</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">Edit</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      
      <template x-for="collect in collections" >
          <tr>
          
            <td style="text-align:center">
                <input :value="collect.name" type="text" style="background-color: #FFF9F5; text-align:center; padding:0">
            </td>
            
            <td @click="updateCollection(collect.id, collect.name)" style="cursor:pointer; text-align:center" class="center">
               <i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square" title="Update info"></i>
            </td>
            
            <td @click="deleteCollection(collect.id)" style="cursor:pointer; text-align:center">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can" title="delete info"></i>
            </td>
            
          </tr>
      </template>
      
    </tbody>
    
</table>
```

```
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('collection', () => ({
    collections: [],
    form: {
      name: ''
    },
   async getCollections() {
      try {
        url = `http://localhost:3001/api/dashboart/collections`;
        const data = await fetch(url);
        const { collections } = await data.json();
        // return collections;
        this.collections.push(...collections);
        
      } catch (e) {
        console.error('Не могу получить данные по категориям');
      }
    },
    async deleteCollection(id) {
      url = `http://localhost:3001/api/dashboart/collections/${id}/delete`;
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          method: 'DELETE',
        });
        const res = response.json();
        console.log(res);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error('Не могу удалить коллекцию', e);
      }
    },
async updateCollection(id, name) {
      const protocol = window.location.protocol;
      const host = window.location.host;
      console.log(name);
      const { href } = new URL(`api/dashboart/collections/${id}/update`, `${protocol}//${host}`);
      // url = `http://localhost:3001/api/dashboart/collections/${id}/update`;
      try {
        const response = await fetch(href, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify({ name, id }),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
        });
        console.log(response.status);
        const res = await response.json();
        console.log(res);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error('Невозможно обновить', e);
      }
    }
  }));
});
```

I tried to use x-model with x-bind, but it didn't work as i wanted. I don't know how to get data, that was binding in value attribute.

Comment: Can you show what have you tried with x-model with x-bind?